# Using HDD memory for the MATLAB

Tags: matlab

As in my previous question I have the following problem. I have a matrix P nxn which elements are matrices P{i,j} which are also nxn. So the total amount of elements is n^4. For n=100 there is an error about the lack of memory. I calculate this matrix only one time and then operate with it. Could you advise me, how to store matrices P{i,j} on the HDD?

I mean that maybe it is possible to store each of them in a file like "data_i_j.dat" and then load it while doing computations in a loop for i and j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `save` function will write data to a file, and the `load` function will read it back again. `save(filename,varname,varname,varname...)`, followed by `S = load(filename)` and referring to `S.varname` (there's also a version of `load` that just dumps stuff into your current workspace, but that seems like poor practice).

Comment: when I load it, it is a structure - how to transfer it into a matrix?

Comment: The structure contains one field for each variable you saved. If you said `save('foo.mat','A')` and then `S = load('foo.mat')` then `S.A` will contain the same thing as `A` originally did.